# Whatsapp Chat Backup

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger, chat

I have got new phone and in that I have lost my whatsapp chat backup as i have skipped to restore and the last backup has been overwriiten by new backup. Is there nay way I can get last backup in my new phone without having old phone

Comment: https://faq.whatsapp.com/android/chats/how-to-restore-your-chat-history

Answer (score 1):

You already answered your question yourself. Last backup has been overwritten by new backup. There is no way to get last backup without having old phone.

Local WhatsApp backup is located Internal Storage

```
/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp
/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.whatsapp/Whatsapp
```

- transfer whole directory to new phone
- install WhatsApp (or clear app data)
- restore local backup on initial setup